# How to show Blazor child component validation message in parent form

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I am trying to submit a form in a blazor web assembly application and in the form, I am using a custom component that will do autocomplete of a field (for company names). The intention is it reuse this component.

I am using the built-in EditForm validation and I have managed to declare the child component field as required (in the child component Company.razor below) but I am unable to pass the field info to the child and the validation message is not kicking in for companyName field.

[image]

I am using mudblazor and here is a usage of my component is below. My question is how do I pass something like `For="@(() => _company.Name)"` so that validation message starts to show like it does for `LastName` field.

```
<EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnSubmit="OnSubmit">
    <MudTextField Required Label="Last name" Class="mt-3" @bind-Value="_model.LastName" For="@(() => _model.LastName)"/>
<CompanyLogo CompanyName="@_company.Name" Required="true" @bind-Company="_company"/> 
</EditForm>

@code { 
    Company _company = new Company(){};
    private EditContext? _editContext;
    private ValidationMessageStore _messageStore;

    readonly CompleteProfile _model = new CompleteProfile();
    ....
    }
```

---

Child component: Company.razor

```
<MudAutocomplete Required="@Required"  RequiredError="Select a company name" T="Company" Label="Company name" 
                 @bind-Value="_company"
                 SearchFunc="@SearchForCompanyName" ToStringFunc="@(element => element == null ? null : $"{element.Name}")" MinCharacters="3" DebounceInterval="200">
    <ItemTemplate Context="element">
        <MudText>
            <img class="img" height="25" src=@ImageSource(element)> @($"{element.Name}")
        </MudText>
    </ItemTemplate>
</MudAutocomplete>


@code {

    Company _company;

    [Parameter]
    public bool Required { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<Company> CompanyChanged { get; set; }

    public string ImageSource(Company company)
    {
      return null; // code remove to keep it simple
      }
    }

----------
```

This is my first blazor app and would highly appreciate any helo. Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to build a custom input component.  In normal (not Mud) Blazor you would do that by creating a component that inherited from one of the `Inputxxx` or `InputBase` components.  There are plenty of articles out there on how to do that.   You are trying to do it with MudBlazor which does "Input" things a little differently.  `Required` is a MudBlazor Parameter that the MudBlazor input component uses to add/remove messages from the message store.  To do what you want you will need to dive into the MudBlazor code - probably  `MudFormComponent` - and figure out how they do it.